# Quais critérios devem ser analisados na escolha de linguagem para a criação de um aplicativo? Desempenho é tudo?

Tags: desempenho, aplicação-desktop

Necessito criar um aplicativo que seja a fonte de comunicação entre diversos outros aplicativos com o banco de dados, ou seja, outros aplicativos farão requisições para esse aplicativo que será criado, e ele terá o dever de se relacionar com o banco de dados e enviar o resultado para o aplicativo que fez a requisição.

Então pensei em criá-lo em alguma outra linguagem que não seja C++ (pois é a que mais tenho conhecimento até o momento) no intuito de aprender uma nova linguagem. Então pergunto: quais critérios devo analisar na hora de escolher uma linguagem para a criação de um novo aplicativo?

Outra coisa que tem me deixado bastante preocupado é o impacto que pode causar usar uma linguagem que possui o desempenho inferior a C++. Eu penso da seguinte forma: quanto maior o desempenho, melhor. Então, se um código em C++ demora uns *0,013ms* para ser concluído, qual vantagem teria eu e meu aplicativo em usar outra linguagem que pode demorar *2,085ms* ou até mais? E em servidores de jogos online, por exemplo, MMORPG que possui todo um sistema de subir de nível, PvP e etc. Essa demora na execução dos códigos poderia interferir na jogabilidade dos usuários?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C++

Sobre a performance seria bom entender que o que dá performance são bons algoritmos, as estruturas de dados corretas, a implementação adequada. Um bom programador pode fazer algo mais rápido em outra linguagem do que um programador ruim pode fazer em C++.

Na verdade a chance de um programador ruim fazer algo terrível em C++ e nem se dar conta é maior que ele fazer algo tão ruim em uma linguagem mais simples, mais alto nível. Digo mais, tem uma chance razoável de um programador ruim fazer em uma linguagem simples e boa algo quase comparável a um programador razoavelmente bom em C++, pelo menos em alguns pontos.

C++ não dá mais performance automaticamente. Ela permite mais performance se tudo for feito certo. Em muitos casos para fazer certo e ter a melhor performance em C++ dá muito trabalho.

Nem tudo precisa dessa performance toda, então é um erro perseguir uma *feature* desta forma.

Na verdade precisaria até definir melhor o que é performance. Só no texto desta pergunta tem pelo menos duas definições diferentes de performance e provavelmente o autor não se deu conta disto.

Um programador bom fará qualquer linguagem ser rápida para o que ele precisa a não ser que realmente não tenha jeito, mas aí ele terá subsídios para definir que ela não serve.

## Outras linguagens

Linguagens não possuem velocidade, elas possuem mecanismos que ajudam muito ou pouco a ter velocidade, se usados da maneira correta.

Claro que a demora pode afetar a jogabilidade. Mas tem um monte de outra coisa que pode afetar mais. E sinceramente não sei se a linguagem mais lenta consegue ser 200X mais lenta que C++ na maioria das coisas. Tem linguagens que serão mais rápidas em alguma coisa.

Claro que linguagens dinâmicas provavelmente estão fora de cogitação porque elas possuem uma diferença grande de performance em muitas operações.

Mas se quer fazer algo em um *browser*, no momento a única opção é JavaScript (hoje não é mais, o [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101) mudou tudo).

Precisa rodar em todas plataformas *mainstream* desktop e mobile? Certamente não poderá ser Delphi ou Java, Swift (até o momento, isso andou mudando um pouco, mas não de todo).

Precisa de um executável monolítico? Não pode ser nada em cima do .NET, até o momento, logo poderá (mais ou menos). Java está no mesmo barco, na verdade hoje nem roda se não instalar a plataforma do Java (também anda mudando).

Precisa de um ecossistema completo, uma comunidade muito ativa? Não pode ser D, Rust, Go, etc. Ou seja, não pode ser nada muito novidade. Nem muito antigo que já é considerado legado.

Alguma linguagem funcional seria adequada? Não tenho como saber, tem casos onde elas são ótimas. Tem que aprender programar de novo, é tudo diferente. Tem casos que elas se comportam terrivelmente.

## Requisitos

Isso só pode ser feito em caso concreto com requisitos claros, e não é o caso da pergunta.

Tem que ter os requisitos antes, depois ver se as linguagens atendem todos eles. Provavelmente nenhuma atende. Então tem que ver quais atendem os mais importantes e em maior número.

## Conclusão

Escolher a linguagem é a parte fácil de fazer algo que exija o máximo de performance. E se confiar no que ler na internet a escolha provavelmente será errada. Tem um monte de gente tentando vender seu peixe mostrado que a sua linguagem preferida é melhor que as outras, e muitos conseguem ser bem convincentes, muitas vezes porque ele acredita naquilo. *Benchmarks* mentem.

Comment: Obrigado! Foi muito esclarecedor.