# O que é WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, compilação, webassembly

Lendo artigos aleatórios, eu li um que previa o fim do JavaScript através do WebAssembly, que parece ser uma forma de fazer com que outras linguagens façam o trabalho do JavaScript, porém tenho certeza que essa é uma definição equivocada.

- O que é WebAssembly? Como funciona?
- Onde irá ser utilizado?
- Como poderá substituir o JavaScript algum dia?
- Como está sua segurança? Afinal, ele permite muitas
  possibilidades e talvez muitas brechas.

Comment: WebAssembly vai acabar com Javascript da mesma forma que [insira uma dentre várias linguagens aqui] ia acabar com o Java.

Comment: @Renan Concordo plenamente, até hoje acho acho o artigo que disse isso (tableless), querendo chamar muita polêmica.

Comment: Um argumento sobre pq usar webassembly: Pense em bilhões de pessoas acessando aplicativos na internet, pense em bilhões de máquinas interpretando gigabytes de scripts e rodando versões interpretadas. Pense no gasto denecessário de tempo de processamento e energia... Talvez não acabe mas possívelmente se tornará preferencial entre os publicadores.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Na época da resposta o WebAssembly não era uma realidade, hoje é e se confirmou o que eu dizia que iria acontecer, mesmo que algumas pessoas discordaram e erraram. WebAssembly disponibilizou diversas linguagens estarem nos navegadores e a popularidade aumenta a cada dia, sem matar o uso do JS.

---

Na minha opinião embasada em quase 40 anos de experiência, para o bem e felicidade geral da nação de programadores, o JS "vai acabar" mesmo :P Ou pelo menos deixará de ser usado por muitos. Mas vamos aos fatos que é o que importa. E para quem não entendeu, isso foi uma piada.

> O que é WebAssembly? Como funciona?

Sabe o que um Assembly? Bom, no final coloco uma série de *links* que podem ajudar entender alguns conceitos básicos sobre o assunto.

O WebAssembly é uma linguagem de baixo nível que tem uma relação de um pra um com instruções de um processador de alguma plataforma. No caso a plataforma é uma máquina virtual, ao contrário de processadores físicos de computadores, e esta plataforma rodará usando tecnologias web, muito provavelmente em um navegador web.

As instruções que ela entende são as mais básicas possíveis (ou quase) para fazer todo tipo de processamento necessário fazendo dela uma [máquina com completeza de Turing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101). Então ela é capaz apenas de, como é comum em assembly, fazer operações básicas de aritmética, relacionais e lógicas, transportar valores entre partes da arquitetura e controlar o fluxo de execução através de um desvio simples condicional ou incondicional. É tudo muito concreto, não tem as abstrações que encontramos na maioria das linguagens. Essas instruções possuem capacidade de executar qualquer coisa se usadas em uma combinação correta.

Então qualquer linguagem poderá ser compilada e gerar um código WebAssembly que poderá ser enviado para os navegadores que executará o que deseja. Dificilmente alguém programará diretamente em WebAssembly, ainda que possível.

Além de permitir que se programe em qualquer linguagem, dará mais flexibilidade e velocidade já que o código não precisa mais ser interpretado.

Na verdade, o conceito geral de WebAssembly envolve outros aspectos, não só a linguagem. Mas isso é o que mais importa para a maioria dos programadores.

> Onde irá ser utilizado?

Em qualquer navegador padrão Web ou outros softwares que desejem ter essa capacidade, se conformando com padrões web que serão definidos para futuro.

> Como poderá substituir o JavaScript algum dia?

Na verdade, JS tem muitos adeptos hoje em dia e por isso **ele não acabará**. Mas é reconhecido que é uma linguagem bem problemática e agora tem-se a chance de poder usar outras linguagens para programar *front end*, então muitos programadores preferirão esta forma.

Ele não foi feito para acabar com o JavaScript, inclusive é possível que no futuro as pessoas programem em JS e gerem um WebAssembly. Haverá uma debandada dos programadores que nunca gostaram do JS mas eram obrigados usar porque não tinha outra opção.

A transição será lenta e só no longuíssimo prazo haverá uma forte migração.

Essas são consequências da tecnologia. Obviamente tem um pouco de especulação (muitas estão se confirmando de forma lenta). Toda vez que é fornecida uma ferramenta que oferece claras vantagens em relação a outra, esta tende enfraquecer a outra mesmo que não seja o objetivo.

A única desvantagem clara e importante do WebAssembly é transitória, já que um dia toda web o aceitará. Existem outras menos óbvias e até subjetivas.

> Como está sua segurança? Afinal, ele permite muitas possibilidades e talvez muitas brechas.

Não tem por que a segurança ser pior. Na verdade, pode ser melhor porque podem resolver alguns problemas que existiam e não podiam mais ser corrigidos e o código será um pouco mais protegido. Não que o código não possa ser visto ou manipulado, mas já não terá serventia para leigos (e muita gente que programa é leiga, por incrível que pareça).

O problema da segurança nunca esteve no Assembly e não estará no WebAssembly. Esse problema é no seu entorno.

- [Veja o Clang sendo usado para rodar C++ no navegador](https://tbfleming.github.io/cib/).
- [Quase um IDE](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/).
- [Mostrando a notação de S-expression](https://wasdk.github.io/wasmcodeexplorer/).
- [Rodando uma aplicação real com Unity](http://webassembly.org/demo/).
- [Rodando C# como SPA](https://github.com/stevesanderson/blazor) (precisa instalar).
- [Jogo em Rust](https://aochagavia.github.io/rocket_wasm/).
- [Estão tentando rodar o Linux no *browser*](https://www.nexedi.com/NXD.Blog.WebLinux).

## Leia também:

- [O que é assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/101)
- [Todo processador utiliza o mesmo conjunto de instruções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109886/101)
- [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101)
- [O que é o código IL e onde eu posso encontrar este código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101)
- [C# é uma linguagem compilada ou interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/101)
- [O que é uma linguagem interpretada? Java é interpretado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101)
- [Como funciona a execução de uma aplicação .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101)
- [Linguagem de programação que não necessitem instalação prévia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117797/101)
- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)

## Conclusão

Conforme minha previsão, que foi contestada na época dessa resposta, o WebAssembly é um sucesso e é usado da forma como eu disse que seria. E claro que o JS segue firme e forte em quem gosta dele.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277151/101).

Comment: Amigo, acho que li algumas inverdades ai nesta sua resposta, WebAssembly não é uma linguagem, é apena uma especificação binária para dar instruções para a vm de forma que o parser seja mais tranquilo que traduzir a linguagem JavaScript escrita, outra coisa que pode deixar os leitores confusos é que você fala como se a linguagem não fosse ser interpretada, na verdade ele vai continuar sendo interpretada.

Comment: Outro ponto que acho importante deixar claro é que WebAssembly é um complemento ao JavaScript já que ela está sendo desenvolvida para acessar a api do JavaScript a partir de uma instrução binária, ou seja, WebAssembly não está sendo criada para substituir o JavaScript.

Comment: Sobre a questão de segurança também acho que a reposta deve ser revista, não tem nada a ver comparar assembly com webassembly, neste caso, basta mencionar que a sengurança do assembly estará atrelada a mesma segurança do JavaScript atual pois é apenas uma mais uma forma de acessar a API do JavaScript. Sobre o código ser visto ou manipulado, deve ser mencionado que mesmo em binário o codigo pode ser debugado e mesmo o código binario tem sua representação escrita legível, ou seja, não deixa de ser código aberto. não há muita diferença do uglify,

Comment: Bom, você já adicionou algumas coisas, embora de uma maneira geral é uma questão mais de opinião ou interpretação, conceituação do que fatos. Se ler a documentação *ipsis literis* e/ou superficialmente de fato conclui-se o que você falou. Se ler tudo, interpretar as consequências de tudo isto e ler o que não está na documentação. Uma coisa é o objetivo oficial, outra é o que ele permite fazer. Eu não quis entrar em detalhes porque não parece ser o objetivo da pergunta. De fato há termos na documentação que fogem do que se costuma conceituar. De certo que ele é mais do que uma linguagem.

Comment: Mas é uma linguagem também, se entender o que é uma linguagem. Ele é interpretado, mas não da mesma forma que o JS. Você mesmo fala em formato binário. O resto está escrito na resposta, mesmo que o seu texto dê a ideia de que não está. Não sei se tem o conhecimento do básico da computação, se tiver alguma dúvida pode criar uma nova pergunta citando esta para que eu esclareça pontos que deseja mais detalhes. Tem *links* na resposta que ajudam entender.

Comment: @Maniero, com tanta tecnologia Web aparecendo, fica difícil de definir uma tecnologia para aprender inicialmente. Comecei a estudar JavaScript e ouvi um podecast ontem, onde era falado sobre JS e o assunto tratado aqui foi abordado, porém, pelo que entendi que o JS não vai acabar e sim diminuir a dependência total dele.

Comment: @DiegoFarias sim, basicamente isto.

Answer (score 2):

- **O que é WebAssembly? Como funciona?**

O WebAssembly é um bytecode. Isto é similar ao JVM, por exemplo. Da mesma forma que várias linguagens compilam para JVM (como o Kotlin, Clojure, Groovy..), várias linguagens compilam para WebAssembly (como Zig, C, Golang, Rust, AssemblyScript, Odin, C#, Swift, Haskell...). É claro, podemos comparar também com compilar para x86, x64, arm64, riscv, mips (...). Obviamente, alguns compiladores (e consequentemente linguagens) são mais eficientes que outros (em geral: Rust, Zig, C tendem a ser os mais performaticos e com menor tamanho).

A especificação possuem extensões, como por exemplo: [SIMD, Reference Type, Multi-Value, Bulk Memory](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/) (...), que podem ser impementadas ou não. *Isso seria algo equivalente à compilar para x64 usando SSE ou AVX512, são recursos que podem ou não estar presente.* O compilador também deve fazer uso desses recursos, *e nem mesmo o LLVM consegue utilizar todos os recursos ainda.*

O bytecode é interpretado e/ou compilado no navegador (ou qualquer outro runtime), assim é executando as instruções.

O WebAssembly não permite chamar qualquer API externa e apenas pode ler informações de sua própria memoria linear. O WebAssembly expõe os "Exports" e "Imports" que se assemelham com DLLs. O programa pode chamar funções importadas e ser chamado através das funções exportadas. Entretanto, aquele executa também deve exportar as funções que foram importadas. Essa tecnica permite chamar WebAPIs dentro do WASM.

- **Onde irá ser utilizado?**

O WebAssembly pode ser usado em qualquer lugar que possua um runtime do WebAssembly.

Ele não está restrito aos navegadores. Um dos outros casos de uso é em "Edge-Computing" ou "Serverless". Em outras palavras, servidores que executam pequenos códigos em WebAssembly, podendo manipular requisições HTTP ou realizar consultas em banco de dados e afins. Para esta finalidade existe o WASI, que é um "sistema operacional", ou seja: predefinindo um padrão de funções que devem ser exportadas e importadas.

- **Como poderá substituir o JavaScript algum dia?**

Isso só irá ocorrer quando permitirem chamar as WebAPIs chamadas dentro do WASM sem qualquer custo adicional de performance.

Quando se refere à "Javascript", imagino que seria comum o seu código chamar coisas como: `querySelector`, `.addEventListener` (...). A cada chamada haverá um custo elevado se isto for feito dentro do WASM. Entre todos os problemas um se destaca: string. A string dos navegadores tipicamente é UTF-16 e a maior parte das linguagens mais modernas (como Rust, Golang, Odin, Swift..) usam UTF-8 por padrão, isso faz com que cada chamada tenha que converter entre um e outro. Além disso, até que o [Reference Type](https://github.com/WebAssembly/reference-types/blob/master/proposals/reference-types/Overview.md) seja utilizado, você precisa fazer um table-lookup no lado do Javascript para acessar os objetos, criando mais indireções. Além disso, há um problema com "linguagens com Garbage Collector", já que o GC não trabalha em conjunto como GC do navegador.

Mas, para casos especificos é possível substituir o JavaScript. Por exemplo, um código que manipula imagens pode ser mais performático em WASM do que em Javascript, e o fato de não precisar chamar as WebAPIs, faz com que tal problema seja irrelevante. O mesmo ocorre com operações criptograficas, onde pode usar o WebAssembly para melhor performance. Você ainda vai precisar do Javascript para chamar tais funções, caso esteja num contexto de navegador.

- **Como está sua segurança? Afinal, ele permite muitas possibilidades e talvez muitas brechas.**

A maior parte das falhas de segurança estão relacionados ao JIT, que transformam o WASM no "assembly real", criando as páginas de execução. Mas, o nível de segurança é equivalente à executar um Javascript no navegador, ele está em um "sandbox".

O JIT também é usado para Javascript, não sendo exclusivo do WASM. Porém, no Chrome não é possível usar WASM enquanto o JIT está desabilitado.