# Estrutura de tabelas em modelo de perguntas e respostas de usuários

Tags: sql, sql-server, modelagem, estrutura-de-dados

Estou com uma dúvida na estrutura de algumas tabelas e espero que possa esclarecer detalhadamente abaixo.

#### Cenário

O sistema irá gerar uma forma de criar **formulários** e **perguntas** dinâmicas, afim de serem respondidas por **usuários** já cadastrados. As **respostas** devem ser armazenadas também.

Um formulário pode estar associado a N clientes, da mesma forma que um cliente pode estar associado a N formulários. Apenas os formulários associados ao usuário poderão ser respondidos. Os formulários possuirão um conjunto de perguntas e em outra tabela deverá ser fornecido a resposta de cada usuário.

#### Dúvida

É necessário que o formulário esteja associado ao usuário para permitir que ele o responda, desta forma criei dois diagramas. Qual deles é o melhor a ser utilizado?

#### Diagrama 1

Através da tabela `Usuario_Formulario` é associado os formulários que cada usuário pode responder e na tabela `Resposta`, irá armazenar cada resposta (referente ao formulário-pergunta) do usuário.

[image: DER]

#### Diagrama 2

Neste segundo diagrama, removo o relacionamento direto de `Usuario`-`Resposta` e faço o relacionamento aparecer entre `Usuario_Formulario`-`Resposta`

[image: DER 2]

Existe alguma outra forma melhor de criar essa estrutura? Pode mexer nos relacionamentos e chaves de cada tabela.

***OBS:*** Não levem em consideração as questões de campos não-chave, apenas criei alguns para dar uma visão melhor do problema.

Comment: usaria o diagrama 2. Faria algumas alterações para ter alternativas em caso de perguntas objetivas e se necessário utilizar a mesma pergunta em vários formulários

Comment: Uma mesma pergunta pode participar de mais de um formulário? // A numeração de cada pergunta é geral ou é por formulário? // Qual a diferença entre usuários e clientes?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta está acima da média, mas ainda é difícil afirmar algo sem saber as necessidades.

Meu entendimento primário é que o 2 é melhor, uma resposta deveria estar vinculada ao formulário e não ao usuário. O formulário já está vinculado com o usuário. Claro, estou só especulando, não sei o problema real.

Não sei, mas acho que está usando uma chave primária composta do ID do usuário e do formulário. Acho, e apenas acho, que deveria ter um `ID` no formulário e `UsuarioID` ser só uma chave estrangeira, aí em resposta só precisaria do formulário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

A modelagem de dados deve ser independente do gerenciador de banco de dados que será utilizado. Somente na etapa de *fisicalização* é que se define a estrutura do banco de dados (tabelas, colunas, chaves primárias, índices etc).

Assumindo que cada pergunta somente pode pertencer a um único formulário, o que percebo é a presença de 3 entidades: USUÁRIO, FORMULÁRIO e PERGUNTA. Além disso, dois relacionamentos: USUÁRIOxFORMULÁRIO e RESPOSTA.

O relacionamento USUÁRIOxFORMULÁRIO estabelece a relação de formulários que cada usuário deve responder. É um relacionamento N:M entre as entidades USUÁRIO e FORMULÁRIO.

O relacionamento RESPOSTA contém as respostas de cada usuário para cada pergunta de cada formulário. É um relacionamento entre as tabelas USUÁRIO, FORMULÁRIO e PERGUNTA onde a resposta é o atributo próprio do relacionamento.

Quanto à implementação física, esboço disponível em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f21d5