# Critérios para escolher linguagem para uso específico considerando o desempenho

Tags: desempenho, característica-linguagem, arquitetura-de-software, independente-de-linguagem

Como determinar qual a linguagem de programação mais apropriada para determinada função?

Por exemplo, para desenvolvimento de IA Python é mais eficiente do que Java.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 11):

É difícil responder isso, mas vejo uma oportunidade para esclarecer algumas coisas que podem ser úteis para muita gente.

Começo por:

> para desenvolvimento de IA Python é mais eficiente do que Java

Por que? Há fontes confiáveis sobre isso?

Python é uma das linguagens menos eficientes que existe, não sei porque IA seria diferente. Estou considerando que a pergunta tem uma *tag* de desempenho.

Não quer dizer que Python não seja adequada, que não tenha seus méritos e menos ainda que não seja usada para isso. São razões sócio-culturais-políticas que fazem Python ser usada para isso e criar a percepção que ela é boa nesse quesito. Eu gosto mais de Python que Java (para algumas coisas), mas não posso dizer que ela é mais eficiente.

Até mesmo porque eficiência carece de definição.

## Ferramenta adequada

[image: Carro andando com um cavalo dentro no banco de trás com a cabeça pra fora da janela]

Existem dois princípios (já que tem isso na pergunta, apesar que eu acho que foi colocado equivocadamente) que regem a escolha de uma ferramenta na computação e outras áreas:

- Use a melhor ferramenta para a tarefa
- A melhor ferramenta é aquela que você sabe

De fato tentar usar uma ferramenta que não se conhece não é uma boa ideia. O correto é aprender a ferramenta antes de usar e aprender bem. Para a maioria das tarefas a ferramenta não é tão importante assim, o usuário dela é que importa, então um bom desenvolvedor resolverá bem o problema com qualquer uma que não seja absurdamente fora.

O problema é que geralmente a pessoa que vai fazer algo não sabe bem nenhuma ferramenta, aí complica. Quem sabe **bem** uma delas costuma não ter problemas em aprender bem outras. Não que isso seja sempre desejável.

## Sem escolha

Tem casos que a ferramenta é escolhida por uma razão exclusivamente técnica, em geral por causa da plataforma onde está sendo usada.

Assembly é usada quando precisa fazer algo que nenhuma outra linguagem consegue, quando precisa acessar o hardware de forma direta, inicializar algo sem nada para ajudar. Ao contrário da crença popular ela não é usada para obter o máximo de performance, pelo menos não na maioria dos casos. Na teoria, Assembly permite a melhor performance, mas na prática é raro conseguir isso, e quando consegue é a custo de muito esforço.

Se vai fazer uma *query* em um banco de dados relacional provavelmente vai usar SQL, que não é uma linguagem de programação, mas T-SQL ou PL/SQL são, e essas linguagens só funcionam em plataforma específica e não costuma dar para usar outra coisa.

Hoje, se vai fazer *frontend* web tem grande chance que usará JavaScript. Mas tem outras linguagens que podem gerar o JS para você. Há motivos para preferir TypeScript, por exemplo. Hoje qualquer linguagem pode ser usada, desde que ela compile para [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101). Para as necessidades atuais para rodar aplicações web JS não é mais tão adequada assim.

Se tem um ERP, um jogo personalizável, um sistema operacional de nicho com limitações do que roda, ou outro software com uma linguagem específica, talvez até proprietária, é essa linguagem proprietária que terá que usar.

Se vai fazer algo para um dispositivo embarcado, com limitações, ou é um sistema operacional, então C, C++ ou até Rust devem ser as mais adequadas, cada uma com suas vantagens. Se vai fazer um *driver* também, precisa acessar os recursos em nível mais baixo.

Se for rodar em Android é provável que Java ou Kotlin sejam opções bem melhores que qualquer outra coisa. Mas C# e outras linguagens podem ser usadas também sem maiores problemas e até com vantagens em alguns casos.

Se for para iOS, Swift ou até mesmo Objective-C podem ser as melhores opções, mas C# e outras linguagens servem bem também, ou até melhor em certos cenários.

Se vai fazer GUI desktop para Windows é quase certo que terá bom retorno com C#, mas praticamente todas linguagens funcionam bem, porque a biblioteca é que faz a diferença. Se quiser fazer GUI com Java, dá, funciona, mas provavelmente não fica bom em plataforma alguma, a linguagem optou por funcionar em tudo, não funcionar bem em algum lugar (tem opções que ajudam nisso, mas não é o padrão e tem lá seus problemas).

Se uma API que precisa usar está disponível para C# e mais nada, é ela que terá que usar.

Até agora a escolha foi sempre em cima da plataforma, isso ajuda decidir quase todas as vezes.

Então se a API de IA ou a plataforma que vai rodar exige Python, Java ou outra linguagem é ela que deva escolher.

Se vai fazer algo rápido, pequeno, que será usado poucas vezes, para seu consumo, ou seja, é um *script*, pode usar quase qualquer linguagem, mas provavelmente a linguagem de shell do sistema operacional é a melhor escolha, pode ser o DOS batch, o Bash, o Sh, o PowerShell, ou linguagens mais gerais como Perl, Python e outras. Nada impede de fazer em C ou Java, mas para que? Códigos chamados *throw away* precisam ser desenvolvidos rapidamente, mesmo que não sejam tão robustos e alcancem boa performance.

Se vai fazer *backend* de web tem grande chance das melhores opções serem C#, Java, PHP, Python, Ruby ou JavaScript. Mas porque não Lua, Delhi, Rust, D, Go, Harbour ou BASIC? Essas primeiras linguagens são melhores porque tem mais e melhores bibliotecas para lidar com web.

R ou Matlab são linguagens ótimas para estatística e matemática, são linguagens de nicho, elas não são boas para algumas tarefas, mas ótimas para as que foram projetadas.

Fortran pode ser uma opção melhor para aplicações científicas.

Tem empresas telefônicas que não podem trabalhar sem Erlang.

Um intrincado e provavelmente mal feito sistema legado pode exigir que um novo projeto seja feito em COBOL para conformar com o anterior.

Se precisar de uma performance específica pode ter que escolher uma linguagem que ajude nisso, que execute rápido, que execute sem pausas (não tenha coletor de lixo ou outras técnicas do tipo), que inicie rápido, não bloqueie a execução (assíncrono), etc. Por isso jogos são feitos primordialmente em C++, mas está mudando.

Tem situações que não pode liberar os fontes ou não pode gerar um executável, e isto pode ser um limitador que elimina várias linguagens. Tem casos que não ter uma instalação complicada, não pode ter DLLs, não pode ter certas dependências, como manter um ambiente de execução, ou tem alguma exigência que uma linguagem não atende. PHP mesmo pode até ser usada para outras coisas, mas qualquer coisa que não seja *backend* web trará um resultado muito ruim por falta de bons recursos para outras tarefas.

Tem problemas que se encaixam bem no paradigma imperativo, outros no funcional. Há casos que a orientação a objeto pode ajudar organizar o código melhor e a linguagem ter um mecanismo bom para isto será útil. Uma linguagem que tenha certos padrões de projeto na linguagem podem dar uma produtividade um pouco melhor.

Se o time que você entrou usa uma linguagem, dificilmente você poderá usar outra.

Certamente eu poderia continuar listando exemplos aqui. Mas a maioria dos problemas importa pouco o que vai adotar. Aí entra a situação que a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você domina.

## Gosto

Gostar de uma ferramenta ajuda motivar a pessoa e isso é bom para a produtividade. Mas não funciona bem em tudo. Por exemplo, as pessoas que mais precisam de uma linguagem de tipagem estática são as que mais desgostam desse tipo de linguagem.

A maior parte do nosso trabalho não é na linguagem de programação. Bom, para alguns até é, porque a pessoa não se planeja, fica tendo que arrumar problemas o tempo todo, mas mesmo nestes casos ainda pode ter que usar muito tempo fora, por exemplo perguntando no SO como resolve o problema que ela não entende, ou ficar no *debugger*.

## Confiar em pessoas aleatórias

Se não consegue determinar por conta própria, tem que perguntar para quem é experiente (em qualidade, não em quantidade de anos fazendo algo) o que é melhor. Se ela for uma boa fonte explicará o porquê. Mas cuidado porque a pessoa pode dar uma explicação que parece ótima para um leigo naquilo, mas não ser.

## Complacência do mercado

Muitas vezes o erro vem antes de escolher a ferramenta adequada. Por exemplo, tem que fazer um ERP e a pessoa escolher fazer para web. Já está errado, aí qualquer decisão será errada. Mas as pessoas estão com sorte, vivemos uma época que soluções sub-ótimas são aceitas no mercado. Por isso na maioria das vezes escolher a linguagem errada não trará grandes problemas. Eu prefiro escolher a certa.

Vejo muito as pessoas quererem fazer de uma certa forma, por exemplo querem programar orientado a objeto, mas não tem base alguma do que sequer isso significa. Em um caso assim que diferença faz a pessoa escolher a linguagem certa ou errada?

## Conclusão

Não se constrói o entendimento de qual linguagem é adequada perguntando isso, e sim aprendendo todos os outros aspectos da computação para ter certeza que pode tomar a decisão de forma adequada. Se você não é especialista em carnes vai comprar 1,5Kg de picanha achando que está fazendo um negocião, ou comprar um peça de 1Kg e achar que é certo que tem qualidade. Só quem sabe mesmo consegue avaliar, não tem métrica universal que responda. Talvez só um especialista em carnes entenderá a analogia :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).