# É possivel substituir a linguagem JavaScript por Python no desenvolvimento web?

Tags: javascript, python, front-end

É possível substituir a linguagem JavaScript por Python, digo, em vez de usar o JavaScript para interagir com o usuário na página web, há alguma maneira de eu escrever essa interação em Python ao em vez de utilizar o JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje não é possível. Talvez seja em breve através do [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101). Mas neste caso específico vejo pouca vantagem. Algumas iniciativas são:

- https://github.com/RustPython/RustPython
- https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

É possível usar "interpretadores" como o [JavaScriphton](https://github.com/metapensiero/metapensiero.pj) para traduzir seu código Python para JS ou mesmo soluções como CoffeScript ou TypeScript para programar numa versão mais limpas da linguagem.