# JavaScript compilado no browser

Tags: javascript, compilação

Existe alguma forma de compilar código JavaScript e distribuí-lo junto com os demais arquivos do site ao invés de distribuir o próprio código fonte? Como no Java que compila para *bytecodes*, assim você distribui seus *bytecodes* e não o próprio código fonte.

Comment: Você pode usar o gulp-javascript-obfuscator, acho que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Hoje em dia não tem muito porque escondê-los. Qual seria a motivação? Ofuscadores de códigos podem estar sujeitos a bugs e podem dificultar a manutenção também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma geral não tem. E compilar por compilar não ajuda muito. Agora existe o [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101) e várias linguagens estão usado ela como *bytecode*, nada impede do JS ser assim também, mas não vi tem nada oficial. Tem iniciativas isoladas, mas não exatamente o que está querendo. [Exemplo](https://github.com/ballercat/walt), pode ter outros, isso muda a "cada" dia.