# LLVM pode ser usada com a linguagem C?

Tags: c, c++, compiladores, projeto-de-compiladores, llvm

Estou estudando compiladores e estou usando a linguagem C e aprendendo sobre o LLVM mas todos os exemplos são em linguagem C++. A pergunta é se consigo usar a LLVM com a linguagem C e como posso iniciar um projeto? Seria apenas clonar o repositório do Github e usar seus códigos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LLVM é um *backend* de compilação, ou seja, ele pega uma linguagem intermediária que é especificada junto de todo ecossistema dele e cria um código alvo para alguma plataforma, que pode ser um código nativo para algum processador ou outro, por exemplo [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101) ou até outra linguagem como JavaScript, eventualmente fazendo otimizações. Ele gera um binário ou outro formato necessário. Ele é um kit que ajuda muito quem vai criar um compilador a se dedicar ao *frontend* que é o importante para uma linguagem.

[image: Linguagens entram no LLVM e sai códigos nativos]

O LLVM é usando pelo Clang, um compilador de C, C++ e outras linguagens derivadas de C. São projetos irmãos. Se usar o Clang está usando o LLVM de alguma forma.

Só faz sentido usar o LLVM diretamente se estiver fazendo um compilador próprio, oque parece ser o caso.

LLVM foi escrito em C++ então toda a API dele é para esta linguagem. Mas é comum que códigos em C++ consigam ser chamados em C, com maior ou menor esforço (em alguns casos precisa de uma camada extra).

Por sorte o LLVM já oferece uma [API pronta para ser chamada por C](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMC.html).

Há um [tutorial independente](https://www.pauladamsmith.com/blog/2015/01/how-to-get-started-with-llvm-c-api.html) mostrando os primeiros passos em C. Parece estar um pouco defasado. Nunca é só clonar o repositório, mas isso será necessário para começar usar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ok muito obrigado! Me ajudou bastante!